# Exception when reading a windows file in linux with java

Tags: java, linux

When reading files with strange characters I get a exception of NoSuchFileException, since java can't handle the file.

Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/tesouraria/adriana2-backup/Cobian Backup 11 diret�rio de testes-2015-10-27 14;34;53

What can I do to handle this?

Comment: I think your java application cannot read paths properly, I would try renaming the file (remove strange characters and spaces) and moving it in a directory without spaces in the path

Comment: How are you reading this file? I assume you incorrectly provided it's name.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Files are files; and "file not found" is thrown when **the file can't be found**; not when the file was successfully opened and found to contain "strange" characters. Could it be your **filename** contains characters that need to be escaped when used as **filename**, like "a b" should better be "a\ b"?!

Comment: If I read you correctly, your file name contains a character that can't be decoded (the funny question mark char). This is usually caused by the character set difference. I suggest changing the name to some simple,as a test.

Comment: I'm having problems changing the characters in linux has well

Comment: Where is the file name come from? user input? hard code in program? Posting related source code could clarify your question. You can use `new java.io.File("/home/tesouraria/adriana2-backup").listFiles()` to get correct file name first.

Comment: Filename comes from a software in windows it was written by the user. Cobian backup
Filename is not seen by windows clients  or linux in the samba share. Only see it by the command line (remote ssh)